# Research Project on How the Revival of the Hebrew Language Led to Jewish Nationalism

Tags: hebrew, history, language

Can someone help me with finding sources (ie, things to read) about my research topic of "How the Revival of the Hebrew Language Led to Jewish Nationalism"

Comment: Did you end up finding some good sources?  My instinct is that the causality happened in the other direction, but I'd love to hear the case for this direction!

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively new book called Resurrecting Hebrew, by Ilan Stavans, which I think will be helpful.

Interestingly, Eliezer ben Yehudah, who was involved in the creation of modern Hebrew as a spoken language, was from a Lubavitcher background.

Comment: I actually read it.  It is interesting.  Written essentially as a novel.  It was a  fast read, and I would recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, try the sections about Ben Yehuda, Bar Ilan, Achad Ha'am, and friends in [The Zionist Idea](http://books.google.com/books?id=n0rDQgAACAAJ&dq=zionist+idea&hl=en&ei=YHThTIykCYSs8AbJzOTnDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA).